# h:dataTable throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/Result

Tags: jsf, datatable, noclassdeffounderror

This is my table:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{registerS.students}" var="registerS.student">
 <h:column>                 
    <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>                   
    #{registerS.student.userName}
 </h:column>
 <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Surname</f:facet>
    #{registerS.student.userSurname}
 </h:column>
 <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">email</f:facet>
    #{registerS.student.email}
 </h:column>
 <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">password</f:facet>
    #{registerS.student.password}
 </h:column>
 <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">classCode</f:facet>
    #{registerS.student.classCode}
 </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

When opening a page with this page, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/Result
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1822)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:82)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:869)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1133)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) has a dependency on [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for several things. One of them is inspecting which `DataModel` should be used behind `<h:dataTable value>`. It also supports JSTL [`<sql:query var="result">`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/query.html) (which is discouraged since a decade, but that aside).

Apparently you're running a barebones servletcontainer instead of a real Java EE server. The stack trace hints that it's [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org). It ships only Servlets, JSP, EL and WS out the box. It doesn't ship all other Java EE stuff out the box such as JSF, JSTL, CDI, EJB, JPA, JTA, JMS, etc..etc.. You have to install it manually (or just move to a real Java EE server such as [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org) or [WildFly](http://wildfly.org)).

You can find a link to the correct JSTL JAR and the correct Maven dependency in "Installing JSF" section of [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).